# Select#select does not behave like manually selecting options in select list

Tags: ruby, webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver, browser-automation

If I have HMTL like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

and I select two options:

```
browser.select.select "Saab"
browser.select.select "Audi"
```

both options are selected:

```
browser.select.selected_options
=> ["Saab", "Audi"]
```

I was expecting just the last one to be selected, like it is when I do the same thing manually.

```
=> ["Audi"]
```

Is this a bug?

Environment: Mac OS X 10.6.8, Firefox 7.0.1, ruby 1.9.2p290, selenium-webdriver 2.10.0, watir-webdriver 0.3.5.

Answer (score 3):

Not a bug, this is because it's a multiple select list, and you are selecting two values in sequence (similar to manually using "command" click).

If you want to just set one, simply clear the list between the calls:

```
browser.select.select "Saab"
browser.select.clear
browser.select.select "Audi"
```

Comment: The question is: why is it behaving like I am holding down ctrl/cmd key? Why isn't it behaving like when you click an option manually? (Unselecting the previous option, and selecting the new one.)

Comment: I imagine it's done for convenience sake, not having to have a separate command to select multiple.

Comment: Also perhaps because we don't have an easy way to do a .control_click so this is perhaps the best alternative to being able to do multi-selects when the option for keyboard modified mouse clicks is not easily (if at all) accessible at the moment in Watir.